# Whats the difference between these git commands?

Tags: git

Can anyone tell me the difference between:

```
git commit -a -m
```

and

```
git commit -am
```

Comment: only reason I ask, is i've been told not to use ".. commit -am" because its wrong. And I want to check there's no functionality loss between the two

Comment: Whoever told you that is wrong. By personal preference, I separate switches that don't take arguments (like `-a`) from those that do (like `-m`), but there's no need to whatsoever, provided you're careful about ordering (ie `git commit -ma 'message' won't work).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latter requires two keystrokes less. Functionally they are equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

It's a pretty standard *NIX convention that single-dash arguments which don't require any parameters, can be combined into a single argument

Answer (score 0):

They can be combined as discussed in the `gitcli` [command line interface] help page `git help cli`, and in the `git rev-parse --help` page